Getting Unknown option "coverageReporters" with value [...] error when running tests in Jest
I have a jest.config.ts file with the following config:
import type { Config } from 'jest';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-require-imports
require('identity-obj-proxy');
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-require-imports
require('jest-environment-jsdom');

const config: Config = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  rootDir: '../',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '.(css)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '@actions/(.*)': '<rootDir>/actions/$1',
    '@app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/app/$1',
    '@components/(.*)': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
    '@domains/(.*)': '<rootDir>/domains/$1',
    '@locales/(.*)': '<rootDir>/locales/$1',
    '@pages/(.*)': '<rootDir>/pages/$1',
    '@styles/(.*)': '<rootDir>/styles/$1',
    '@tests/(.*)': '<rootDir>/tests/$1',
    '^d3-(.*)$': `<rootDir>/node_modules/d3-$1/dist/d3-$1`,
    'react-markdown':
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-markdown/react-markdown.min.js',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$': [
      '@swc/jest',
      {
        sourceMaps: true,
        minify: false,
        jsc: {
          parser: {
            syntax: 'typescript',
            tsx: true,
            decorators: false,
            dynamicImport: false,
          },
          transform: {
            react: {
              runtime: 'automatic',
            },
          },
        },
        module: {
          type: 'commonjs',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'jsx', 'tsx'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./tests/setup-client.ts'],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['^.*WithLoading.tsx$'],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    './domains/**/*.*',
  ],
  coverageReporters: ['lcov', 'text', 'text-summary'],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 60,
      functions: 70,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 80,
    },
    './components/': {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 80,
    },
  },
  testMatch: [
    '**/components/**/*.test.[jt]s?(x)',
    '**/domains/**/*.test.[jt]s?(x)',
    '**/tests/**/*.test.[jt]s?(x)',
  ],
};

export default config;


I'm not sure how to fix the issue. Any recommendations would be helpful.
